# Returning a value from Database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

What do I need in order to return a value after inserting data in Database?

here is my code for the controller action:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult InsertData(int? key)
    {
        var TestData = new Data();
        DataContext.InsertData(TestData);

        return Content(TestData.Key);
    }
```

Here is the error I get:

The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.Mvc.Controller.Content(string)' has some invalid arguments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is telling you you are passing the wrong data type in it needs to be a string

Try:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult InsertData(int? key)
    {
        var TestData = new Data();
        DataContext.InsertData(TestData);

        return Content(TestData.Key.ToString());
    }
```